# Can't get urls count from spider (Scrapy)

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to get number of urls to scrape in `SitemapSpider`. I tried to override `start_requests` method but it prints 0. I have one `sitemap_url` which contains thousands of urls. I want to get count of these urls.

This is what I tried but I suppose Urls from sitemap aren't in start_urls.

```
class MainSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'main_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['...']
    sitemap_urls = ['http://.../sitemap.xml']

    def start_requests(self):
        r = super(MainSpider, self).start_requests()
        self.urls_count = len(self.start_urls)
        print self.urls_count 
        return r
```

Do you know how to get the number?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below.

```
class MainSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'main_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['...']
    sitemap_urls = ['http://.../sitemap.xml']

    def start_requests(self):
        r = super(MainSpider, self).start_requests()
        r_list = list(r)
        print len(r_list)
        return r_list
```

The `super(MainSpider, self).start_requests()` returns a generator and list will make sure you get the complete yields made. But this will slow down your scraper startup in case of large sitemaps. The actual scrapy may start with a delay

Comment: This counts length of sitemap_urls. I want to get number of urls found in Sitemap. Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible, but not straight forward. The problem is that you need to download all these site map urls which are then to be processed by `_parse_sitemap` in your class. So it is possible but with decent modification. You will need to create a response object for each url in the `start_requests` methods and then pass them through `_parse_sitemap` and get the list from those generator.